# I need to connect a device to the internet through an ethernet cable but I don't have access to my modem - how can I do this?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, modem

I have a device (a mailing machine) I need to set up for work that needs to be connected to my modem via an ethernet cable but I don't have access to my modem so I'm unable to connect to it. Is there any kind of way to use my laptop for the same purpose through some kind of adapter without having to gain access to my modem (I live in apartments and have no access to it at all)? If so, what kind? I've called technical support for the device and they weren't helpful at all and I don't want to end up purchasing the wrong thing.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you *physically* have no access? Usually that's all that is needed; there are no admin settings for connecting a cable.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use your laptop to connect to WiFi and then share that through ethernet. (I am assuming you are using windows 10).

1. Open up settings (`win` + `i`)
2. Click on `Network & Internet`
3. On the main `Status` page scroll down until you see `Advanced network settings`
4. Click on `Change adapter settings`
5. Right click on the WiFi adapter and select `Properties`
6. Switch to the `Sharing` tab
7. Check the box that says `Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection

This should allow you to connect an ethernet cord to your laptops ethernet port and plug it into a device to connect to the internet.